# Trim country code from phone number in php

Tags: php, regex

I will get a country code as `$countryCode` and a phone number as `$phone_no`. The phone number will have country code at the start so I have to remove country code from the `$phone_no` and get plain phone number without any code attached.

For example if country is Indonesia I will be getting:

```
$country_code = '62';
$phone_no = '+62509758151';
// need to  get 509758151
```

Currently I am trying with regex and trim function

```
$result = ltrim( preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$phone_no) , $country_code);
// $result is 509758151
```

which works in this case but fails when phone number is starting with digits mentioned in the country code for ex. `$phone_no = '+62609758151';`

```
$result = ltrim( preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$phone_no) , $country_code);
// $result is 09758151 which is incorrect
```

Not to mention it will also fail for trivial cases like +62629758151

Please suggest something.I am aware of string based solutions like `substr()`, etc. but I am looking for some regex-based solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change start of string with sign + and country code

```
$result = preg_replace("/^\+?{$country_code}/", '',$phone_no);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/925842)

Comment: Maybe even make the plus optional ( \+*) in case they get a phone number missing the plus sign? Just a thought.

Comment: @CMiller added but  this is to OP opinion :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! .Always wanted to learn regexp suggest any book/resource?

Comment: Unfortunately, can't. I didn't study them, just I used Internet to know about, when solve problems

Answer (score 1):

```
        $mobile='1234567891';Mobile number like this.
        $numberwith_country_code='+911234567891';Mobile with country code like this.


        $mobile                 =   preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$_POST['mobile']);
        $str                    =   strlen($mobile);
        $numberwith_country_code=   preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$_POST['numberwith_country_code']);
        $numberwith_country_code=   substr($numberwith_country_code,0,-$str);
```

output like this:-
mobile->1234567891
numberwith_country_code->+91

js plugin link:-https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-International-Telephone-Input-With-Flags-Dial-Codes.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pick only the 2 prefix digits:

```
  \+\K\d{2}
```

If you want the whole prefix:

```
  \+\d{2}
```

Comment: I think some country codes are single digit, like the US (+1).

Comment: In that case you need to detect the region first and than activate different regex mythology